# OS X terminal always screws up its display of text when SSHed into other servers

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app

When I'm SSH'd into any other server with Terminal..

Text will start display over hidden text, when I search through history, text will only show fragments. When I start typing, letters will appear within those fragments. Or characters will appear that are phantoms, and as I type, the letters I'm writing will overwrite them.

I only customized small things like fonts and colors in Terminal.

This has existed in Mac Terminal for at least five years of me using them. Why does this happen and what can I do against it?

Comment: Its the mac os x terminal. It can be reproduced by SSH'ing into any remote. The app is called.. Terminal. Not sure how to answer which shell. Root shell? I've customized small things like font and color, but like I said the problem has persisted for at least five years. Many thanks slhck!

Comment: Sure! I think it would be really helpful to see screenshots of the problems you experience. Like, showing us what exactly you type in, and what happens. I've cleaned up the comments in the meantime if you don't mind.

Comment: The first thing to check is whether the remote host has appropriate terminfo files installed. In the remote shell, run the command `infocmp`. It will either display terminfo information or an error complaining that it can't locate the terminfo data. If you get an error, there are workarounds, but the solution is to install/update the ncurses package.